# Handle GWT super-source in Eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, html, eclipse, gwt

I want to emulate some Java classes and therefore I use the `super-source` tag in a gwt.xml module.

I created two eclipse projects one only for the super sources and another which contains the app code.

The super source project has the following structure:

```
/
/super/Emul.gwt.xml
/super/emul/EmulatedJavaClass.java
```

`Emul.gwt.xml` contains:

```
<super-source path="emul"/>
```

In eclipse I right clicked on the `super` folder and added it to the Build Path. That works fine. The problem is that eclipse shows an error on the package tag of my emulated java files.

In my emulated package I cannot use:

```
<super-source path=""/>
```

This will give an error while compilation.

**Can I do something that Eclipse does not show an error in the package and still have all the nice eclipse features like code completion?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no enough info about your complete structure in eclipse, but normally:

- Your module.gwt.xml should not be in the super path but in the normal folder for sources, ie: `src/com/example/Module.gwt.xml` with the entry `<super-source path="super"/>`
- Then you can put your super folder in the src, ie: `src/super/com/example/MySuperClass.java`
- In eclipse you have to configure in your project class path `src` and `src/super`, but when configuring `src` there is an option to put exceptions so set `src/super` as exception.